# Position of scaling points

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way to position the scaling points inset rather than centered over the border of an object?

This is the default postition of the scaling points

[image]

And I'm looking for somthing like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't really find a property to accomplish this (although I could have sworn one exists), but it is fairly straightforward to do this for an object.  Pulling from the fabricjs source, I tried modifying the drawControls function like so:

```
if (this.hasInsideControls) {
    width -= scaleOffset;
    height -= scaleOffset;
}
```

Basically, it checks to see if the object has this flag (which is normally non-existant) and if so, modifies the position of the corners a little.  There's a small conditional at the end to ensure the rotating point is drawn correctly, too.  I haven't tested this with groups, but it seems to work fine for objects.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

http://jsfiddle.net/z7k8gjm0/1/